# TFS 2012 Automatic workitem State Change

Tags: tfs, workflow, tfs-workitem

I defined new work item with tfs power tools on tfs 2012 server.

new work item name is cab. states: new, active, deployed, closed.

I linked (releated) two User Story to cab work item.

I want to automatic state change(closed) which linked user story when cab work item state changed(deployed)

how to? c# coding? tfs event service? workflow action? or any way?

I don't found article for this requrement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with pure WorkItem workflow.
I would use a Server plugin to trigger event. See [this design](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/assafstone/archive/2011/07/29/how-to-write-a-robust-tfs-server-plugin-with-job-extensions.aspx).
Only downside is that you have to remeber adding and configuring this plugin on every AT node and after upgrade/migration of TFS.